# mongoDB query to Java code [$and condition for lte and gte]

Tags: java, mongodb

How to write Java code for the below MongoDB query

```
db.getCollection('testing')
      .find({"Mid" : "652ba8c0", 
             "sname" : "biole", 
             "timeVal" : { $gte : ISODate("2017-03-14T13:40:39.117Z")
                        , $lte : ISODate("2017-03-14T14:30:12.419Z")}
            })
      .sort({"timeVal" : -1})
```

I tried writing like below, but it does not fetch any records, instead it should fetch the available records (for the above MongoDB query it fetches 200 records)

```
dbCollection.find(Filters.and(Filters.eq("XDK", engno),
                              Filters.eq("sensorName", sensor),
                              Filters.gte("timestamp", startMinusDate),
                              Filters.lte("timestamp", startPlusDate)))
             .sort(new BasicDBObject("timestamp", 1));

dbCollection.find(Filters.and(Filters.eq("XDK", engno),
                              Filters.eq("sensorName", sensor),
                              Filters.and(Filters.gte("timestamp", startMinusDate), 
                                          Filters.lte("timestamp", startPlusDate))))
            .sort(new BasicDBObject("timestamp", 1));
```

I am using below jar file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How do your dates look like ? What is the value for `startMinusDate` and `startPlusDate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MongoDB Java driver;

```
Document document = new Document();
document.append("Mid" , "652ba8c0").append("sname" , "biole");
document.append("timeVal" , new Document().append("$gte", startMinusDate).append("$lte", startPlusDate));
collection.find(document).sort(new Document().append("timeVal", -1));
```

Comment: The above is not working for date field.  But when i try this for integer field.. code for integer field. But the same is not working with date field. (i tried the dates separately, it is working correctly, hence i data is not problem, somehow date field is not working)












Document document = new Document();
document.append("lb", 5);
document.append("ub", new Document().append("$gte", 14).append("$lte", 16));
dbCollection.find(document).sort(new Document().append("ub", 1));

Comment: The code i tried in post as well working, it is problem with date format. Hence converted it to UTC format.